# Rails 5: STI null key when save record on join table record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-many-through

I have this scenario.

```
class StoreSubscriptionProduct << ApplicationRecord
end

class SpecialProduct < StoreSubscriptionProduct
  has_many :special_product_item_groups
  has_many :item_groups, through: :special_product_item_groups
end

class ItemGroup << ApplicationRecord
  has_many :special_product_item_groups
  has_many :special_products, through: :special_product_item_groups
end

class SpecialProductItemGroup < ApplicationRecord
  # special_product_id
  # item_group_id

  belongs_to :special_product
  belongs_to :item_group
end
```

Controller:

```
class SpecialProductsController < BaseController

  def create
    special_product = SpecialProduct.new(permitted_params)
    if special_product.save
      # blah
    else
      # blah
    end
  end
end
```

The current issue that I have is when on my controller I receive the params for creating a SpecialProduct and send the item_group_ids via params.
When creates the join table record the `special_product_id` its `nil`

Inside the validation, the `item_group_id` is ok, but the `special_product_id` is not assigned.

```
=> #<SpecialProductItemGroup:0x007fdb3c4905b0
 id: nil,
 special_product_id: nil,
 item_group_id: 1,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil>
```

I'm missing some foreign_key or another option in order to assign the `special_product_id`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your STI table is `item_groups` where you have `type` column created:

```
class SpecialProduct < StoreSubscriptionProduct
  has_many :special_product_item_groups, class_name: 'SpecialProductItemGroup'
  has_many :item_groups, class_name: 'ItemGroup', through: :special_product_item_groups
end

class ItemGroup < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :special_product_item_groups, class_name: 'SpecialProductItemGroup'
  has_many :special_products, class_name: 'SpecialProduct', through: :special_product_item_groups
end

class SpecialProductItemGroup < ApplicationRecord
  # special_product_id
  # item_group_id

  belongs_to :special_product, class_name: 'SpecialProduct'
  belongs_to :item_group, class_name: 'ItemGroup', foreign_key: :item_group_id, optional: true
end
```

If your STI is `special_products` then change foreign key appropriately. In addition you can check [this discussion on Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28552).